# How I can save JSON Api on device and use it when the device is not connected to internet

Tags: flutter

I tiring to made app that get data(Images and titles) from a web site as json api and put this data in a ListView bulider,

but I want to save the data on device first to view it when the device isn't connected to the internet and I want the data who I save it , be different order

Comment: If you are dealing with images, i suggest you take a look at [Flutter Advance NetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage) which provides caching out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Shared Preferences Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store a Map
on the device.

I recommend reading [Data Persistence with Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence) in the Cookbook. This will show you how to tackle this.

You could use  [SQFLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) if you are familiar with SQL or [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) if you prefer to stick with pure dart